# discord.py how to get message from the user again?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

in discord.py rewrite, I am trying to make a vote system. Voting could require spaces, like

```
!vote do this option    or do that option
```

So I want to get 2 messages with the same user.

At First, I used `@client.commmands()`, but I think using `on_message` is going to be better, but any of them is okay.

 I am thinking of this,

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(ctx): #We only get ctx because it can contain spaces
    userid = ctx.author.id
    @client.event
    ....
```

So my question is, is there any function it will make it so you can get content from same user 2 times, and can you use `@client.event` in `async def`.

Any Solutions? Thanks.

Comment: is the voting sent as "!vote do this option  or do that option" or as "!vote do this option", "or do that option" ?

Comment: No, I am trying to send multiple messages by the same user, like
 "!vote" & 
 "first option" & 
"second option"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the desired functionality through 2 ways.

- Save the last message a user sent.
- Wait for a new option in the vote command

As the last thing is better. I will explain how to do that.

**Step 1: Create your !vote command**

```
@client.commmands()
async def vote(ctx):
    # logic to do some things when someone votes
```

**Step 2: Add logic that [`waits_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) the options**

We use a timeout on the [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for), so it wont go on forever, because we use a timeout we need to catch the exception it raises. This is done with the try, except. We also use a while loop, because this enables us to receive as many options as possible. Note that the condition in the while loop can be changed.

```
@client.command()
async def vote(ctx):
    # logic to do some things when someone votes

    try:
        # While the user inputs options
        while True:
            await __handle_vote_option_message(ctx)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        # The user did not respond in time.
        return

async def __handle_vote_option_message(ctx):
    timeout_ = 10
    message = await client.wait_for('message', check=lambda message: message.author == ctx.author,
                                    timeout=timeout_)
    if not __is_message_valid_vote_option(message):
        # logic to handle incorrect vote options
    else:
        # Whatever you want to do with the option the user provided.

def __is_message_valid_vote_option(message):
    # check if message is correct.
    return message.content.startswith("option")
```

---

This way is in my opinion far better than filling the `on_message` event with this kind of logic. As the logic belongs to the vote command not the `on_message` event.

Comment: @IQ.tree I still had my version of the code in. I use cogs and they require classes. It worked on my pc so the new edit should work for your situation

Comment: Thanks. the new edited code works.
But you should edit your code @client.commands() to @client.command(). Thanks for your help.

Comment: @IQ.tree if it helped you make sure to accept the answer and upvote it!